# I am getting an error that I don't understand Discord.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

Here is my code:

```
import os
import discord
import re
from discord.ext import commands

SERVER_ID = os.environ['SERVER_ID']

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix='^', intents=discord.Intents.all())


@bot.event
async def on_ready():
  print(f"Bot logged in as {bot.user}")

#////////////////////////////////////////

#async def dm_roles(member):
#  print(f"DMing roles to {member.name}")

 # await member.send("""Here are your roles!
 # Pick a color:
 # Red
 # Green
 # Blue
 # Purple
  
 # Now pick a language!
 # Javascript
 # Python
 # C#
 # C
 # C++
 # Java
 # Rust
 # Go
 # """)

async def dm_roles(member):
  print(f"DMing roles to {member.name}")

  await member.send(f"""Hi, {member.name}! Welcome to {member.guild.name}! 
  Here are your roles!
  Pick a color:
  Red
  Green
  Blue
  Purple
  """)

# def server_id(id):
  # return id

# @bot.command
# async def guildid_init(ctx):
  # SERVER_ID = server_id(ctx.message.guild.id)
      # alternative is at line 53

async def assign_roles(message):
  print("Assigning roles...")

  colors = set(re.findall("Red|Green|Blue|Purple", message.content, re.IGNORECASE))

  color_emojis = set(re.findall("\U0001F534|\U0001F7E2|\U0001F535|\U0001F7E3", message.content))

  for emoji in color_emojis:
    {
      "\U0001F534": lambda: colors.add("Red"),
      "\U0001F7E2": lambda: colors.add("Green"),
      "\U0001F535": lambda: colors.add("Blue"),
      "\U0001F7E3": lambda: colors.add("Purple"),
    }[emoji]()

    if colors:
      server = bot.get_guild(SERVER_ID)

      # roles = [discord.utils.get(server.roles, name=language.lower()) for language in languages]
      new_roles = set([discord.utils.get(server.roles, name=color.lower()) for color in colors])

      member = await server.fetch_member(message.author.id)

      current_roles = set(member.roles)

      roles_to_add = new_roles.difference(current_roles)
      roles_to_remove = new_roles.intersection(current_roles)
      
      try:
        await member.add_roles(*roles_to_add, reason="Roles given by Elijahs Utils Bot.") # I could change this to a function quote with the bot's tag
        await member.remove_roles(*roles_to_remove, reason="Roles revoked by Elijahs Utils Bot") # I could also change this to a function quote with the bot's tag
      except Exception as e:
        print(f"Error: {e}") # I could also instead of this, only printing {e}
        await message.channel.send(f"Error assigning/removing roles. Error: {e}")
      else:
        if roles_to_add:                                                             # was (colors)                                          was (colors) without list
          await message.channel.send(f"""You've been assigned the following role{'s' if len(roles_to_add) > 1 else ''} on {server.name}: { ', '.join([role.name for role in roles_to_add]) }.""")

        if roles_to_remove:                       # could also use "You've lost"       # was (colors)                                        was (colors) without list
          await message.channel.send(f"""You've been revoked of the following role{'s' if len(roles_to_remove) > 1 else ''} on {server.name}: { ', '.join([role.name for role in roles_to_remove]) }.""")
    else:
      await message.channel.send("No supported colors were found in your message.")

@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
  if message.author == bot.user:
    return

  if isinstance(message.channel, discord.channel.DMChannel):
    await assign_roles(message)
    return
    
  if message.content.startswith('^roles'):
    await dm_roles(message.author)
# was ^serverid
  elif message.content.startswith('^guildid_init'):
   # await message.channel.send(message.channel.guild.id)

    SERVER_ID = message.channel.guild.id
    print(f"{message.author} initalized guild id variable with {SERVER_ID}")
token = os.environ['TOKEN']
bot.run(token)
```

And here is my error:

```
2022-11-06 03:17:07 INFO     discord.client logging in using static token
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 119, in <module>
    bot.run(token)
  File "/home/runner/Elijahs-Utils-Bot-Python-edition-2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 828, in run
    asyncio.run(runner())
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/asyncio/runners.py", line 44, in run
    return loop.run_until_complete(main)
  File "/nix/store/2vm88xw7513h9pyjyafw32cps51b0ia1-python3-3.8.12/lib/python3.8/asyncio/base_events.py", line 616, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "/home/runner/Elijahs-Utils-Bot-Python-edition-2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 817, in runner
    await self.start(token, reconnect=reconnect)
  File "/home/runner/Elijahs-Utils-Bot-Python-edition-2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 745, in start
    await self.login(token)
  File "/home/runner/Elijahs-Utils-Bot-Python-edition-2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/client.py", line 580, in login
    data = await self.http.static_login(token)
  File "/home/runner/Elijahs-Utils-Bot-Python-edition-2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 801, in static_login
    data = await self.request(Route('GET', '/users/@me'))
  File "/home/runner/Elijahs-Utils-Bot-Python-edition-2/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/discord/http.py", line 680, in request
    raise HTTPException(response, data)
discord.errors.HTTPException: 429 Too Many Requests (error code: 0): <!DOCTYPE html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="no-js ie6 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="no-js ie7 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="no-js ie8 oldie" lang="en-US"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js" lang="en-US"> <!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<title>Access denied | discord.com used Cloudflare to restrict access</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=Edge" />
<meta name="robots" content="noindex, nofollow" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />
<link rel="stylesheet" id="cf_styles-css" href="/cdn-cgi/styles/main.css" />


<script>
(function(){if(document.addEventListener&&window.XMLHttpRequest&&JSON&&JSON.stringify){var e=function(a){var c=document.getElementById("error-feedback-survey"),d=document.getElementById("error-feedback-success"),b=new XMLHttpRequest;a={event:"feedback clicked",properties:{errorCode:1015,helpful:a,version:1}};b.open("POST","https://sparrow.cloudflare.com/api/v1/event");b.setRequestHeader("Content-Type","application/json");b.setRequestHeader("Sparrow-Source-Key","c771f0e4b54944bebf4261d44bd79a1e");
b.send(JSON.stringify(a));c.classList.add("feedback-hidden");d.classList.remove("feedback-hidden")};document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(){var a=document.getElementById("error-feedback"),c=document.getElementById("feedback-button-yes"),d=document.getElementById("feedback-button-no");"classList"in a&&(a.classList.remove("feedback-hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!0)}),d.addEventListener("click",function(){e(!1)}))})}})();
</script>

<script defer src="https://performance.radar.cloudflare.com/beacon.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="cf-wrapper">
    <div class="cf-alert cf-alert-error cf-cookie-error hidden" id="cookie-alert" data-translate="enable_cookies">Please enable cookies.</div>
    <div id="cf-error-details" class="p-0">
      <header class="mx-auto pt-10 lg:pt-6 lg:px-8 w-240 lg:w-full mb-15 antialiased">
         <h1 class="inline-block md:block mr-2 md:mb-2 font-light text-60 md:text-3xl text-black-dark leading-tight">
           <span data-translate="error">Error</span>
           <span>1015</span>
         </h1>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">Ray ID: 765aaca46f788108 &bull;</span>
         <span class="inline-block md:block heading-ray-id font-mono text-15 lg:text-sm lg:leading-relaxed">2022-11-06 03:17:07 UTC</span>
        <h2 class="text-gray-600 leading-1.3 text-3xl lg:text-2xl font-light">You are being rate limited</h2>
      </header>

      <section class="w-240 lg:w-full mx-auto mb-8 lg:px-8">
          <div id="what-happened-section" class="w-1/2 md:w-full">
            <h2 class="text-3xl leading-tight font-normal mb-4 text-black-dark antialiased" data-translate="what_happened">What happened?</h2>
            <p>The owner of this website (discord.com) has banned you temporarily from accessing this website.</p>
            
          </div>

          
      </section>

      <div class="feedback-hidden py-8 text-center" id="error-feedback">
    <div id="error-feedback-survey" class="footer-line-wrapper">
        Was this page helpful?
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-yes" type="button">Yes</button>
        <button class="border border-solid bg-white cf-button cursor-pointer ml-4 px-4 py-2 rounded" id="feedback-button-no" type="button">No</button>
    </div>
    <div class="feedback-success feedback-hidden" id="error-feedback-success">
        Thank you for your feedback!
    </div>
</div>


      <div class="cf-error-footer cf-wrapper w-240 lg:w-full py-10 sm:py-4 sm:px-8 mx-auto text-center sm:text-left border-solid border-0 border-t border-gray-300">
  <p class="text-13">
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1">Cloudflare Ray ID: <strong class="font-semibold">765aaca46f788108</strong></span>
    <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    <span id="cf-footer-item-ip" class="cf-footer-item hidden sm:block sm:mb-1">
      Your IP:
      <button type="button" id="cf-footer-ip-reveal" class="cf-footer-ip-reveal-btn">Click to reveal</button>
      <span class="hidden" id="cf-footer-ip">34.121.103.117</span>
      <span class="cf-footer-separator sm:hidden">&bull;</span>
    </span>
    <span class="cf-footer-item sm:block sm:mb-1"><span>Performance &amp; security by</span> <a rel="noopener noreferrer" href="https://www.cloudflare.com/5xx-error-landing" id="brand_link" target="_blank">Cloudflare</a></span>
    
  </p>
  <script>(function(){function d(){var b=a.getElementById("cf-footer-item-ip"),c=a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip-reveal");b&&"classList"in b&&(b.classList.remove("hidden"),c.addEventListener("click",function(){c.classList.add("hidden");a.getElementById("cf-footer-ip").classList.remove("hidden")}))}var a=document;document.addEventListener&&a.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",d)})();</script>
</div><!-- /.error-footer -->


    </div><!-- /#cf-error-details -->
  </div><!-- /#cf-wrapper -->

  <script>
  window._cf_translation = {};
  
  
</script>

<script>(function(){var js = "window['__CF$cv$params']={r:'765aaca46f788108',m:'I1QejZ.cgvNpoklISu1Uqp3dUMDkdAY6qpKI.IJGL50-1667704627-0-AVZhKLnB+ub5tSZMK76DZsOo1hvBAd9u36G0VHm87Y4xZCSUJPn4T7tFtULspdZK4m/er58v3Ti3B3Yv4K2jEjRJyUx4mA+Pe4rrchlMOQ944cSFf0H8b6k7PUn0d1pKFF1kydcsXAtrLoHsvo1waQo=',s:[0xa7086e3695,0x89dab2daa4],u:'/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g'};var now=Date.now()/1000,offset=14400,ts=''+(Math.floor(now)-Math.floor(now%offset)),_cpo=document.createElement('script');_cpo.nonce='',_cpo.src='/cdn-cgi/challenge-platform/h/g/scripts/alpha/invisible.js?ts='+ts,document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_cpo);";var _0xh = document.createElement('iframe');_0xh.height = 1;_0xh.width = 1;_0xh.style.position = 'absolute';_0xh.style.top = 0;_0xh.style.left = 0;_0xh.style.border = 'none';_0xh.style.visibility = 'hidden';document.body.appendChild(_0xh);function handler() {var _0xi = _0xh.contentDocument || _0xh.contentWindow.document;if (_0xi) {var _0xj = _0xi.createElement('script');_0xj.nonce = '';_0xj.innerHTML = js;_0xi.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(_0xj);}}if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {handler();} else if (window.addEventListener) {document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', handler);} else {var prev = document.onreadystatechange || function () {};document.onreadystatechange = function (e) {prev(e);if (document.readyState !== 'loading') {document.onreadystatechange = prev;handler();}};}})();</script></body>
</html>
```

Can someone tell me what is going on and how to fix it? I am trying to make a role bot in discord.py. I keep getting this error, and I don't know why there is an error with line 119. I had no errors earlier, and I am thinking that it is an issue with the installed frameworks for discord.py. Do you know what the error is and how to fix it? Is my code outdated with the current versions of discord and discord.ext? I think it is a compiler error? I am using replit, and I uninstalled discord.py, and reinstalled. I have no idea what is wrong.

Comment: Check that your token is read properly from the environment and valid.

Comment: I did. I used it in a environment variable in replit

Comment: is the token read as a string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Too many requests` means you're getting ratelimited for spamming Discord's API. *You* may not be doing so, but because you're abusing replit's platform to run a bot on, other people's bots share the same IP address, and as a consequence all of you combined get ratelimited.

Don't use replit (or heroku, or any other non-vps site) to host a bot. This is one of the reasons why, but there's countless more.

Comment: Do you know of any good online IDE's?

Comment: Also, would it be the same if I ran it infinitely through flask

Comment: @that_common_coder Yes it would, and no there's no online IDE's. Any specific reason you can't work locally?

Comment: I don't have a lot of space on my mac, and when I need to make room, I don't want to have to uninstall something.

Comment: Most IDE's don't take up _that_ much space. Consider having a look around your mac for things you no longer need, or getting a storage upgrade of some sorts.

Comment: I mean the pip packages and modules.

Comment: I ran it with flask, but I am still getting ratelimited

Comment: Running it with flask has nothing to do with getting ratelimits...